# Is this a natural way to say “I’m really tired because I’m sick”

Tags: phrase-meaning, verb-endings, beginners

제가 아파지 대문에 정말 피곤해고 있어요.

Sorry if there are spelling mistakes etc!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is not grammatical.

It should be: 제가 아프기 때문에 정말 피곤해요.

피곤하다 is an adjective describing a state, so you can't say 피곤하고 있어요 which would be like "I am being tired" in English.

Also, although the above sentence is now grammatically correct, it is not the best way to say it.

A better way would be: 저는 아파서 정말 피곤해요 or 저는 몸이 아파서 정말 피곤해요.

VERB-기 때문에 typically gives a reason that is a little involved and might require a logical explanation or special emphasis.  Readily understood reasons for common things  are expressed with -아서/어서 instead, as in 몸이 아파서 집에서 쉬었어요 (I rested at home because I was sick), or 케이크를 너무 많이 먹어서 속이 메스꺼워요 (I feel nauseous because I ate too much cake). This kind of reason doesn't take any logical reasoning or special emphasis, so -아서/어서 works better than 때문에.